# Finding the limit in an $∞ - ∞$ case

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to ∞}6x^{2/3} - 2x + 1$$
How can I find the right side and left side limit to this function? It is an ∞ - ∞ case. I know I need to convert this function into a $∞/∞$ or $0/0$ case so that I can use the l'hopital's rule, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Note that you have a notational error: the expression should be $\lim_{x\to\infty}(6x^{2/3}-2x+1)$. There shouldn't be an equals sign separating the limit symbol and the expression you're taking the limit of. The way you write it, you're suggesting that the limit as $x$ goes to infinity of $y$ is equals to that expression of $x$, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a change of variables $u=x^{1/3}$. Then $u$ goes to infinity as $x$ does, and your limit becomes
$$\lim_{u\to\infty}-2u^3+6u^2+1.$$
This is a cubic with negative leading term, so it goes to $-\infty$.

In other words, $u^3$ grows more quickly than $u^2$ as $u\to\infty$, so the cubic term dominates both the quadratic and constant terms.

Comment: I did not know that. So I could have just applied that logic to the original expression? (because $x^1 > x^{2/3}$)

Comment: @RudyGoburt, yes you could do it directly like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is the following:

$$f(x)-g(x)= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{g(x)}}=\frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{f(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)g(x)}}$$ so you have the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ from the form $\infty-\infty$.